# Database joining in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am new in ASP.NET MVC 3 and am searching on the Internet, but I found nothing on how I can **use joining in ASP.NET MVC 3**. For example, in my social networking project I want to get all the posts with comments. I am using:

```
var myobj = DB.Comments.Include("Post").ToList();
```

But this shows only those posts which have comments. I want to show all posts and then their respective comments.

I have asked a similar question and people replied that use

```
var myobj = DB.Post.Include("Comments").ToList();
```

But that is wrong. My knowledge of databases is saying that a post has comments, not that the comments has posts. Simply COMMENT has a foreign key from POST.

How do I resolve this in a simply database query or method?

```
    var myobj = from u in DB.Posts
                    join b in DB.Comments
                    on u.UserID equals b.UserID
                    into obj
                    from ua in obj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    select new { userComments = (ua == null) ? "" : ua.UserComments, UserPosts = u.UserPosts };
    return view(myobj.ToList());
```

If I use the above then I can't pass it into the view, because it is an SQL query and the `and` view requires a model whatever the case. What is the complete solution in both cases, that is, from using the SQL query or is there any other method?

Comment: This has nothing to do with MVC...

Comment: You are finding nothing because you have confused ASP.NET/MVC (a web front-end API) with the Entity Framework (a LINQ-provider enabled ORM)

Comment: then sir how to resolve this kindly help me out

Comment: What is wrong with the solution others gave you? Comment has a foreign key **to** (**not from**) post = post has many comments.

Comment: relationship between post and comments, PK of post i.e postId is present in comments

Comment: Yes, `PostId` is present in comments. And this allows you to use eager loading: `DB.Post.Include("Comments").ToList();` is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are doing an inner join, AKA just Join. This means it has to match.

Instead, use an outer join. [Example](http://www.hookedonlinq.com/OuterJoinSample.ashx).